Будто и деепричастие
Неуверенность освобождает от ложного представления, будто только пренебрегая эмоциями окружающих, мы сможем существовать в нашем жестоком мире.
Нужна ли запятая во втором случае?

Правильно:
Неуверенность освобождает от ложного представления, будто только пренебрегая эмоциями окружающих, мы сможем существовать в нашем жестоком мире.
Пояснение

Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, союз БУДТО в значении союза ЧТО. Придаточное осложнено деепричастным оборотом. Первая запятая ставится между главным и придаточным предложением, вторая запятая закрывает деепричастный оборот.

Сравнить: Неуверенность освобождает от ложного представления о том, что только пренебрегая эмоциями окружающих, мы сможем существовать в нашем жестоком мире.


Думаю, что такой вариант более корректен по стилю, но надо смотреть по тексту.
